# A suitable constructor for my type using DI could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, simple-injector, hangfire

I have a .NET core WebAPI project that uses Hangfire for background jobs. I am trying to setup Simple Injector for DIs. My porject has an `IFoo` and a `Foo` class that looks as follows

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo() { }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Foo::DoSomething");
    }
}
```

Below is how I setup the Simple Injector container. I am using `Hangfire.SimpleInjector` nuget package

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
        container.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(
            new Hangfire.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container));

        services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(<My Connection string>));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
}
```

The background job is setup as following in controller

```
public IActionResult DoSomething()
{
    var jobID = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IFoo>( x => x.DoSomething());

    return Ok();
}
```

But this job fails with following stack trace.

> An exception occurred during processing of a background job.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException A suitable constructor for type
> 'MyWebAPI.Controllers.IFoo' could not be located. Ensure the type is
> concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public
> constructor.

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider, Type, Object[])
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider, Type)
at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter, PerformingContext, Func`1)
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext, IEnumerable`1)
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext, IStorageConnection, String)
```

What am I doing wrong in setting all this up?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I do see the problem: Simple Injector isn't invoked to resolve your type. The stack trace shows that Handfire is just calling the core DI infrastructure.

Comment: Your code isn't telling .NET Core's DI to use SimpleInjector anywhere. You need to call `services.AddSimpleInjector(container,...)`

Comment: The use of `GlobalConfiguration` seems suspect

Comment: Might it be that `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator` doesn't work i.c.w. `AddHangfire`? Have you tried calling `services.AddSingleton<IJobActivator>(new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the DI in `Hangfire` is for this purpose.

You need dependency injection to resolve inner dependencies,
not to resolve the main type you want to use.

You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544802/1543596) answer with same problem.